# Android Telnet client send

Tags: java, android, sockets, telnet

Hi i'm just starting android studio for the most part. i'm following [this](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/) tutorial on setting up sockets trying to get familiar with things. i can compile and run the application in the tutorial but the server i'm trying to send data to is a telnet server. the server just sits and waits for specific strings to do specific things. how can i modify this code to send strings to the telnet server? please ignore any invalid indents in the code from pasting it.

```
package com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Client extends Activity {

private Socket socket;

private static final int SERVERPORT = 23;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.0.50";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        String str = et.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        out.println(str);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: or is this code actually sending the string but i need to encode it into bytes?

Comment: please help me!!